# what does read() in urlopen('http.....').read() do? [urllib]

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

Hi I'm reading "Web Scraping with Python (2015)". I saw the following two ways of opening url, with and without using `.read()`. See `bs1` and `bs2`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('http://web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html')
bs1 = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

html = urlopen('http://web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html')
bs2 = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

bs1 == bs2 # true


print(bs1.prettify()[0:100])
print(bs2.prettify()[0:100]) # prints same thing
```

So is `.read()` redundant? Thanks

Code on p7 of Web scpraing with python: (use `.read()`)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
```

Code on p15 (without `.read()`)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Comment: In addition to the answers above, I suggest you try to use the requests library for HTTP requests

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

You'll be more in control of the HTTP response

Comment: thanks @A.Romeu could you refer me some post for more info please? I do need to fit form and get response webpage in the next step, where I plan to use `mechanize`

Comment: On the link I sent you, there is a lot of information on how to use it, under the section 'The User Guide'. You can start directly with http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting [BS docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup):

> To parse a document, pass it into the BeautifulSoup constructor. You
>   can pass in a string or an open filehandle:

When you're using .read() method you use an "string" inteface. When you are not, you're using "filehandle" interface.

Effectively it works same way (although BS4 may read file-like object in lazy way). In your case whole content is read to string object (it's may consume more memory unnecessarily).

Answer (score 5):

[urllib.request.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) returns a file-like object, the `read` method of it will return the response body of that url.

`BeautifulSoup` constructor accepts both a string or an open filehandle, so yes, `read()` is redundant here.

Answer (score 3):

**Without BeautifulSoup Module**

.read() is useful when you are not using the "BeautifulSoup" Module thus making it non-redundant in this case. Only if you use .read() you will get the html content, without which you will just have the object returned by .urlopen()

**With BeautifulSoup Module**

The BS module has 2 constructors for this feature, one will accept String and the other will accept the object returned by .urlopen(*some-site*)